# How to append string into sortedset value on Redis

Tags: java, redis

I have the following sortedset:

```
zadd cross:10 2015122018 userIds=14
```

How would you append new value (**only if not exited**) when adding to the same score.

The only way I can think of is getting on my app the result, extract appending and adding again:

get value:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE cross:10 2015122018 2015122018
```

let's say I want to append 15 (if not existed):

```
 zadd cross:10 2015122018 userIds=14,15
```

Is there a way to do this on redis without extracting the value on my app?

(in case value not existed just **append** if value existed than **ignore**)

Thank you.

Comment: How do you plan to access those userIds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sorted set can have multiple values with the same score, so you probably don't need to store the ids as a comma separated string, just add the id to the sorted set:

```
> ZADD cross:10 2015122018 14
(integer) 1
> ZADD cross:10 2015122018 15
(integer) 1
> ZRANGEBYSCORE cross:10 2015122018 2015122018
1) "14"
2) "15"
```

If you really need to store a set of ids related to each element of a sorted set, you should consider writing a Lua script, as @ItamarHaber suggested.

Something like this for example to *add a userid*:

```
local zkey = KEYS[1]
local score = ARGV[1]
local value = ARGV[2]
local zmember = redis.call('zrangebyscore', zkey, score, score)
local result = 0
if (zmember[1]) then
    result = redis.call('sadd', zmember[1], value)
else
    local skey = zkey .. ':' .. score
    result = redis.call('sadd', skey, value)
    redis.call('zadd', zkey, score, skey)
end
return result
```

So you can add the userId 14 and 15:

```
redis-cli --eval /script.lua cross:10 , 2015122018 14
redis-cli --eval /script.lua cross:10 , 2015122018 15
```

To retrieve the userIds for a particular score, you can do it in two operations, (or even in one if the scores never changes):

```
> ZRANGEBYSCORE cross:10 2015222018 2015222018
1) "cross:10:2015222018"
> SMEMBERS cross:10:2015222018
1) "14"
2) "15"
```

Comment: The lua is great. but if I can "append" like members on the same score and get them why would I need it?

Comment: You don't need it. With the Lua script, you only gain the ability to handle the values as a SET, so you can for example calculate the intersection between two members with [SINTERSTORE](http://redis.io/commands/sinterstore), etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set members are immutable - they can only be added or deleted. To mimic an "append", you'll need to remove the old member and add the new (appended) one. Scores, however, can be changed.
2. To append if exists w/o extracting in your app, consider writing a Lua script that performs all the logic.

Comment: "need to remove the old member and add the new (appended) one" thats describes my example-solution right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident that a Redis Sorted Set will do the legwork for you. I.e.: not add a member, but only change it's score when it already exists.

In other words it seems you can go ahead and just do the `zadd cross:10 2015122018 userIds=14,15` and be done with it.

The effect would be that the score would be updated for an existing member, and the member would be inserted for a new member (and linked to the score)

Comment: How the member will be just inserted and not override ?